# I'm new to java and CPLEX. Struggling with summations and arrays

Tags: java, arrays, cplex

I'm trying to write a code in Java with CPLEX but I have a problem. I'm new to CPLEX and Java as well.

I've studied for a few days and I could understand very simple CPLEX examples but I have to deal with something much more difficult now.

I was trying to write expressions like `1000*(k-Sigma y^k(k from 1))` but I couldn't make it work so I googled for this topic but I couldn't find a way to figure this out.

What I understood so far is I need an array like this

```
IloNumVar[] y = cplex.numVarArray(?, ?, Double.MAX_VALUE?);
```

I read the manual from the IBM website but I still don't understand what variables I should put inside brackets.

And I need a for loop for the summation so I wrote like

```
for(int k = 1; k <= bus; k++) {
    objective.addTerm(1000, k-y[k]);
}
```

Of course it's not working. I guess something's wrong with 'k' but have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Totally unfamiliar with cplex, but maybe `objective = objective.addTerm(...);`? (When addTerm creates a new object instead of altering itself.)

Comment: Thanks.. but I'm sorry I just gave up on this

Comment: Never give up :)

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the following page:

[CPLEX Java API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.5.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/concert/IloModeler.html#numVarArray(int,%20double,%20double))

You can see the following method header:

```
IloNumVar[] numVarArray(int n, double lb, double ub)
```

where the params are:

```
n - number of variables
lb - lower bound
ub - upper bound
```

If you use it like this:

```
IloNumVar[] y = cplex.numVarArray(5, 0, Double.MAX_VALUE);
```

you are going to create an array of 5 elements (variables). Each of them has to be a non-negative number.

Please specify more clearly the 2nd part of your question.